# How do I replace a single character like 'A' with something like "10"?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, replace, stdstring

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () 
{
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.size (); i++)
    {
        if (s[i] == 'A')
        {
            s[i] = "10";
        }
        cout << s[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting following error:

```
main.cpp: In function
'int main()': main.cpp:10:5: error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]  s[i]= "10";
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why can't I edit this question to change the code format?

Answer (score 4):

You can find the position of `A`, starting from index 0 until end of the string and whenever you find, `replace` it with `10` using the information of both position where you found and the length of the string you would like to find in the given string.

Something like follows: https://www.ideone.com/dYvF8d

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::cin >> str;

    std::string findA = "A";
    std::string replaceWith = "10";

    size_t pos = 0;
    while ((pos = str.find(findA, pos)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        str.replace(pos, findA.length(), replaceWith);
        pos += replaceWith.length();
    }

    std::cout << str << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

why not use `string::find()` to locate the character you want to replace and then `string::insert` to **insert** a "10"? maybe not the best way, but can finish it correctly.

You code's question is that the `operator[]` of `std::string` returns a `char&`, and you can not assign a `string literal` to it.

And I think I should give you a function to implement it.

```
void Process(std::string& op)
{
    auto pos=op.find('A');
    op.erase(pos,1);
    if(pos!=std::string::npos)
    {
        op.insert(pos,"10");
    }
}
```

Comment: For simplicity I would not introduce the function here, especially since it was not in the original problem

Comment: Got my vote for replacing the loop with a `find`. I would just like to add that assuming `std::size_t` here is an implementation detail. It will be better to just adapt to the library with `auto pos = op.find();`. Or, if C++11 is not an option: `std::string::size_type pos = ...;`

Comment: You are not *replacing* the `A` with `11` at all, you are just *inserting* the `11` next to the `A`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau haha, I forgot to delete it, sorry, editing the answer!

Comment: @TomdeGeus That makes sense, but I write function just because easy to write and reusable.